# load package data with separate name

Tags: r, dataset, loaddata

I want to load different package data but assign them in separate object. There are some packages which has data with same name. I want to load them but as a separate object. For example;

```
data("milk", package = "EMSC")
data("milk", package = "baseline")
```

But the later will replace the previous. So, I want to assign them on object Eg. `milk.emsc` and `milk.baseline`.

Is there any efficient and simple solution for this?

Comment: You can place it in different environment and extract it

Comment: assign to a variable before loading the other package?

Answer (score 1):

Since I came to this question after a long time, I will write my answer that I came up with in case someone has the same problem.

```r
local({
    data("milk", package="baseline", envir=environment())
    assign(x="milk_baseline", envir=.GlobalEnv, value=milk)
})
local({
    data("milk", package="EMSC", envir=environment())
    assign(x="milk_emsc", envir=.GlobalEnv, value=milk)
})
```

This way the global environment will be clean and will only have two data sets with same name from two different packages.